# Operators(and , or) in JSON Structure

Tags: java, json, protocol-buffers

I have never seen this kind of JSON before and I am not sure how this structure can be generated using code.In below Json structure `offerings` cantains an array of objects as well as an object with `OR` operator. Can somebody explain how is this valid JSON structure and how can we generate proto buffer for this kind of JSON structure?

```
{
            "id": 147,
            "display_text": "Entertainment available",
            "quality": "better",
            "cost": "free or paid",
            "exists": "yes",
            "type": "streaming",
            "updated_at": "2019-01-30T09:13:30Z",
            "offerings": [
                [
                    {
                        "delivery_medium": "in-seat",
                        "content_type": "livetv",
                        "selection_type": "live"
                    },
                    "and",
                    {
                        "delivery_medium": "in-seat",
                        "content_type": "movies",
                        "selection_type": "loop"
                    }
                ],
                "or",
                {
                    "delivery_medium": "streaming",
                    "content_type": "avod",
                    "selection_type": "on-demand"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a cute use of json arrays ... This might help explain it

`offerings` is an array with three elements in it.

- element [0] is a sub-array also with 3 elements in it - an object, a string with the value `and` and another object
- element [1] is a string with the value `or`
- element [2] is an object defining some values.

It's easier to see in one of the tree view JSON validators.

The user of this then has effectively a tree against which they could do some processing (perhaps using it as rules for making some sort of decision).

Note: From https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html

> Arrays are used for ordered elements. In JSON, each element in an array may be of a different type.

Comment: Sorry didn't deal with protobuf part of the question yet.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) ([RFC7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.html)) does not include any logic or arithmetic operators, or operators in general. JSON is just defined as a "data interchange format".

Your example is syntactically valid - since different value types can co-exist in a JSON array - but besides that, those "and" and "or" operators do not mean anything. Most likely, a program that is meant to process that JSON will assume the presence of these values and implement some sort of logic.